# How to access the one customized list view's child into the another customized list view's child?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I am new to the Android Development. And I am stuck with the Customized list view.

Actually, in my activity there is two customized list view say list1 and list2.

Each list view's row having CheckBox, TextView and Delete button.

Now, my problem is that if in list1, for any row if the check box button is checked then at that time I also have to checked the checkbox of list2's child also.

I don't understand how to access the list2's child into the list1.

Please help me.
Thanks in Advance...:)

Answer (score 0):

Use the function setOnItemClickListener of list1. You can get the position of the value you have selected. Take that position and use it to select the value in list2

Comment: Hello...Venkat...Thanks for the response.

Comment: Did u get the result?